# Python cannot import (cython) shared library

Tags: python, c++, cython

the last few days, I managed to compile rnnlib as shared library. It is a c++ library. I want to call it from python. My choice fell to cython. so I created a a c++ function
`void libCall(int argc, char* argv[])` which is actually the same as the main function of rnnlib but renamed to make it easier callable. the rnnlib library is /usr/lib

My **rnn.pyx** looks like that

```
# distutils: language = c++

cdef extern from "libcall.hpp":
    void libCall(int argc, char* argv[])

cpdef call():
    print 'hallo welt'
```

My **setuprnn.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
import os

os.environ["CC"] = "gcc"
os.environ["CXX"] = "g++"
os.environ["CFLAGS"]="-I./src/"

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
       "rnn.pyx",            # our Cython source
       libraries=["rnnlib","netcdf_c++","netcdf","m","stdc++"],  # additional source file(s)
       language="c++",             # generate C++ code
      ))
```

I have created an additional test file to see if the library can be called.
**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "libcall.hpp"

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    libCall(argc, argv);
}
```

Now when I build test.cpp with

> g++ -Wall -I./src/ test.cpp -lrnnlib -lnetcdf_c++ -lnetcdf -lm -lstdc++ -o test

I can run it and everything works.
And when I run python setuprnn.py build_ext -i I get rnn.so and rnn.cpp, which is nice. But when I run python and enter `import rnn`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: ./rnn.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5NcVar3getEPcPKl
```

I looked into rnn.so with nm and got this:

```
000000000003f140 W _ZNK5Mdrnn5printERSo
             U _ZNK5NcDim4sizeEv
             U _ZNK5NcVar3getEPcPKl
```

so I assume the constant exists in the library?

I cannot figure out why. I found a similar thread [Python ImportError - undefined symbol - for custom C++ module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643666/python-importerror-undefined-symbol-for-custom-c-module) but do not know how to apply it here:

```
python setuprnn.py build_ext -i
Compiling rnn.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing rnn.pyx
running build_ext
building 'rnn' extension
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I./src/ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c rnn.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rnn.o
......

g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I./src/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rnn.o -o /media/psf/dfki/test/rnn.so
```

When I searched for it. I only found this site http://upstream.rosalinux.ru/compat_reports/netcdf/3.4_to_3.5.0/abi_compat_report.html

So I thought of a backward compatibility issue and that is why I installed netcdf library 4.1.3, because this is fully backward compatible

I hope someone can help me, because it is really frustrating.

Comment: Please attach also output of `ldd ./rnn.so` and `sudo ldconfig -p|grep netcdf` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry that I did not post earlier, I am really busy right now. 
So yes in general hughdbrown you are right. It should work. The problem is the dependencies of my libraries. Cython does not catch it.

The python script from above (setuprnn.py) does nothing else but execute this:

```
cython ...
gcc ...
g++ ... -lrnnlib -lnetcdf -lstdc++ -o rnn.so
```

This creates a problem as stated above in the entry post. The solution is then just to create a shell script for creating the library:

```
#!/bin/sh
cython ...
gcc ...
g++ ... -o rnn.so -lnetcdf_c++ -lnetcdf -lm -lstdc++ -lrnnlib
```

I hope this helps future generations to not waste many hours :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate your problem. Here is the script I created to create the files, build the extension, and run the code in python:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

echo "Cleaning up /tmp"
rm -f /tmp/rnn.pyx /tmp/rnn.so /tmp/setuprnn.py /tmp/libcall.hpp /tmp/rnn.cpp /tmp/rnn.so
rm -rf /tmp/build/

echo "Creating /tmp/rnn.pyx"
cat > /tmp/rnn.pyx << EOF
# distutils: language = c++

cdef extern from "libcall.hpp":
    void libCall(int argc, char* argv[])

cpdef call():
    print 'hallo welt'
EOF

echo "Creating /tmp/setuprnn.py"
cat > /tmp/setuprnn.py << EOF
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
from distutils.extension import Extension
import os

os.environ["CC"] = "gcc"
os.environ["CXX"] = "g++"
os.environ["CFLAGS"]="-I./src/"

setup(ext_modules = cythonize(
       "rnn.pyx",            # our Cython source
       libraries=["rnnlib","netcdf_c++","netcdf","m","stdc++"],  # additional source file(s)
       language="c++",             # generate C++ code
      ))
EOF

echo "Creating /tmp/libcall.hpp"
touch /tmp/libcall.hpp

echo "Building rnn.so extension"
python setuprnn.py build_ext -i

python -c "import rnn; print('-' * 30); print('Imported rnn'); print(dir(rnn))"
```

Here is the result I get:

```
Cleaning up /tmp
Creating /tmp/rnn.pyx
Creating /tmp/setuprnn.py
Creating /tmp/libcall.hpp
Building rnn.so extension
Compiling rnn.pyx because it changed.
Cythonizing rnn.pyx
running build_ext
building 'rnn' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
gcc -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I./src/ -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c rnn.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rnn.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wstrict-prototypes’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -I./src/ build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/rnn.o -o /tmp/rnn.so
------------------------------
Imported rnn
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__test__', 'call']
```

Looks good to me. Of course, I don't have a correct implementation of all your code and nothing I wrote pulls in netcdf or the other libraries you cite. Maybe you could update your description so that others can test this out?