# Python, ImportError: undefined symbol: g_utf8_skip

Tags: python, compilation, distutils

There are like tens of similar questions on StackOverflow, but after several hours of lurking I finally gave up.

So I'm trying to write a C extension for Python. Let's call it `mylib`. Here is the header file:

**mylib.h**

```
#ifndef mylib_H
#define mylib_H

#include <Python.h>
< ... >
#include <glib.h>
< ... >
```

and **setup.py:**

```
from distutils.core import setup, Extension

include_list = [
    "/usr/include/glib-2.0", "-lglib-2.0",
    "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include"
]

module = Extension('mylib', ['mylib.c'])

setup(name='mylib', version='1.0', 
      include_dirs=include_list,
      ext_modules=[module])
```

If I run `python setup.py install`, I get the following (which I take as successful installation):

```
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'mylib' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I-lglib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c mylib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/mylib.o
mylib.c: In function ‘c_sound_utf8’:
mylib.c:117:5: warning: ‘g_unicode_canonical_decomposition’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/glib-2.0/glib/gunicode.h:627) [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
     decomposition = g_unicode_canonical_decomposition(c_composed, &decomposition_len);
     ^
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/mylib.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mylib.so
running install_lib
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/mylib.so -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mylib-1.0.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mylib-1.0.egg-info
```

But when I try to use `mylib` from inside Python, I get the following:

```
>>> import mylib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mylib.so: undefined symbol: g_utf8_skip
```

After rambling around StackOverflow for some time I got an idea that I should either **1.** rebuild the needed library or **2.** [put all the links to needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11643666/python-importerror-undefined-symbol-for-custom-c-module)  library *after* all generated module names.

Rebuilding didn't work (or I did it the wrong way). As for placing links to the needed library after everything else - well, I didn't find out the way to make `distutils` change the order of links in its compile string. **Is there a way?**

I also tried providing `extra_link_args`/`extra_compile_args` to my extension (without any effect):

```
module = Extension('mylib', ['mylib.c'], 
                   extra_link_args=["-Xlinker", "-export-dynamic"])
```

I felt pretty miserable and kept googling on. Then I found out about **SWIG**. I decided to try it by making another library, *(uppercase)* `MYLIB` (I changed filenames and all text occurences of `mylib` to `MYLIB`). I wrote a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

GLIB_IMPORT_OPTS="-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -lglib-2.0"
PY_IMPORT_OPTS="-I/usr/include/python2.7/ -lpython2.7"

swig -Wall -python MYLIB.i
gcc -fPIC -Wall -c MYLIB.c $GLIB_IMPORT_OPTS
gcc -fPIC -Wall -shared MYLIB.o MYLIB_wrap.c -o _MYLIB.so $GLIB_IMPORT_OPTS -L. $PY_IMPORT_OPTS $GLIB_IMPORT_OPTS
```

When I ran this thing, everything worked fine (I could import the library and do stuff with it). Here, as you can see, links are at the very end of the compile line. So now I'm trying to understand: what did I miss with the `distutils` way? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 2):

Well, actually I found the solution. A had to add *library links* to `extra_link_args`:

```
extra_link_args=["-I", "/usr/include/glib-2.0", "-l", "glib-2.0", "-I", "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include"]
```

which appends them to the end of compile string.

Answer (score 0):

I found adding -fPIC to "extra_compile_args" in the Extension constructor also helped.  Like so:

```
my_module = Extension('modulename',
                      ...
                      extra_compile_args=["-fPIC"]
                      sources = ['mycode.c'])
```